# ConcurrentModificationException in Codename One app

Tags: codenameone

In my Codename One app that involves (Android) Native interface implementation, I receive on the device from time to time a ConcurrentModificationException which stack trace reads :

```
W/System.err: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
W/System.err:     at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidAsyncView.flushGraphics(AndroidAsyncView.java:380)
W/System.err:     at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation.flushGraphics(AndroidImplementation.java:1147)
W/System.err:     at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.paintDirty(CodenameOneImplementation.java:580)
W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1075)
W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:997)
W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
W/System.err:     at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

My code (Codename One part or the native interface implementation) does not use `ArrayList` andthe app can continue after clicking OK when the 'Internal Error' pops up, but I would prefer to avoid this error.

Where should I look at to prevent this error from happening ?

Any help greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

That means code is triggering a native repaint for some reason on a separate thread. Does your native code that interacts with the peer component do so using the Android native UI thread?

If not that might trigger a race condition.

Comment: In the native code calls `AndroidImplementation.runOnUiThreadAndBlock()` to launch the camera and its preview which makes sense to me since this code block is actually modifying the UI. Later the code calls `AndroidImplementation.runOnUiThreadAndBlock()` again to set the view brightness. Please note that since making the changes described in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40916205/6351897) the exception is gone. Does this make sense to you @Shai ?

Comment: That could make sense although it's hard to judge if the "and block" aspect of it is correct without digging deep into the code.